# Unable to automatically discover Git tags with Jenkins multibranch pipelines, Bitbucket Server, and Webhook to Jenkins for Bitbucket Server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-server

## BLUF

I am unable to configure our Jenkins multibranch pipeline job to scan and build when a new tag is pushed to our remote Bitbucket Server repository. New branches and commits are discovered and built. New tags remain undiscovered until a manual scan

What have I configured incorrectly?

## Software & Plugins

Jenkins v2.141
Basic Branch Build Strategies Plugin v1.0.1
Git plugin v3.9.1

Bitbucket Server v5.13.1
Webhook to Jenkins for Bitbucket Server v4.4.4

## Jenkins Configuration

[image: Jenkins Configuration]

## Bitbucket Server Configuration

[image: Bitbucket Server Configuration]

I originally wanted to use the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin, however a [documented issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51063) prevents it from recognizing new tags.

Comment: You can setup Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin ( https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin ) to trigger on tags. And I would have that in its own pipeline job, separated from multibranch pipeline jobs. Because you tag a commit, not a branch.

You can configure variables like:

 - `eventKey` as `$.eventKey`
 - `changes_ref_ids` as `$.changes[?(@.ref.type == "TAG")].ref.id`

And a filter with text `$eventKey` and expression `^repo:refs_changed$`

When the job is triggered you will have the tag name in a variable named `changes_ref_ids_0`.

Comment: I specifically want to use a single multibranch pipeline so that I do not have to set up and configure multiple jobs. Our current non-pipeline configurations do require multiple jobs, one per branch and tag, I would like to move away from this setup.

Comment: You can use Job DSL Plugin to automate the creation of these tagging jobs. You may do some Groovy to invoke the Bitbucket Rest API and determining repositories to automate the process. https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin